# How to take name and its code using JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to making weather application. I am new on android.My goal is finding different location's weather on this app. For example, when I choose a "00000.1.17.352"it  will give me Adana but I can not change location because it depends on code. I want to take code depending on name. Here is my JSONparser.

[image: JSON Values for "name" and "code"]

If I write name to editview, I want to get its code. Here is my layout and java code.

```
    <EditView
        android:id="@+id/city_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"/>
```

There I am fetching city name and city code.

```
public class CityFetch  {

private String urlString = null;
public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
private String cityCode = "cityCode";
private String cityName = "cityName";
public CityFetch(String url){
    this.urlString = url;
}

 public String getCityCode(){

    return cityCode;
}

public String getCityName(){

    return cityName;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);


        cityCode= reader.getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray("cities").getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("code");

        cityName= reader.getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray("cities").getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("name");


        parsingComplete = false;



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void fetchJSON(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

                readAndParseJSON(data);
                stream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
}
```

So how can I access "code" when I write name to the editview field? Is it possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: hi can you try with this way.. i have made easy to get our json data.. from any url check out from here http://saveen-android.blogspot.in/2014/10/json-parsing.html

Comment: I edited my question. My problem is not parsing. My main problem is that when I take "code", it should give me "name" too. I can not reach name via code.

Comment: what do you mean by "can not reach name via code" ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution - loop all cities and compare until you find one you seek.

```
JSONArray cities = reader.getJSONObject("data")
            .getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONArray("cities");

for (int i=0; i<cities.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jCity = cities.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jCity.getString("name");
    if (name.equals("Adana Bolge")) {  // << replace with city you wish to search
        String code = jCity.getString("code");
        return code;
    }
}
return null;  // or throw exception - no such city found
```